# Combining unique cell's values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, filtering, unique

I'm trying to get the combined values from column B from a list in column A that contains duplicates names.

```
Sally  Cookies, Apples
Jamie  Pie
Sally  Muffins
Bob    Jam
Bob    Pie
```

and have the result be:

```
Sally  Cookies, Apples, Muffins
Jamie  Pie 
Bob    Jam, Pie
```

I've tried sorting with Unique, but I only get the first instance of the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in columns **A & B** like:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub GatherData()
    Dim Na As Long, Nc As Long, v As String
    Range("A:A").Copy Range("C1")
    Range("C:C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Na = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Nc = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To Nc
        v = Cells(i, "C").Value
        Cells(i, "D").Value = ""
        For j = 1 To Na
            If v = Cells(j, "A").Value Then
                Cells(i, "D").Value = Cells(i, "D").Value & "," & Cells(j, "B").Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    For i = 1 To Nc
        Cells(i, "D").Value = Mid(Cells(i, "D").Value, 2)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Will produce:

[image]